# Synchronous transactions in Cordova SQLite Plugin lite4cordova

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I'm looking for a way to execute synchronous transactions with the lite4cordova plugin and can't find any example.

In the plugin's webpage there are a lot of example of asynchronous transactions, but can't find one so far.

Can anyone give me an example of how to execute a synchronous transaction? is it even supported by the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Every transaction on database has been run on a separate thread that why they implemented it in this way. All Transaction on lite4Cordova are asynchronous. If you want to make it synchronous you have to understand the native code in case of android the Java code of the plugin has to be changed.

Comment: I think you are not able to communicate synchronously between JavaScript and Java with Cordova. No amount of Java code change will bring synchronous behavior to a Cordova plugin. SQLite is synchronous only within pure Java code.